# How to create a label inside an <input> element?

Tags: html, forms, label, placeholder

I would like to insert a descriptive text inside an input element that disappers when the user click on it.

I know it is a very common trick, but I do not know how to do that..

What is the simplest/better solution?

Comment: For the record, the http://attardi.org/labels/ solution suggested by Tex is actually better than the one from Cory Walker.

Comment: Horrible UX, proven time and time again.

Comment: The image didn't work. Deleted it from post. Still available in [revision 3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/781473/3).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
<input name="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" type="text" value="search">
```

A better example would be the SO search button! That's where I got this code from. Viewing page source is a valuable tool.

Comment: Slight extension to your solution: <input name="q" class="textbox" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'" type="text" value="search">

Comment: You can use defaultValue property, so you'll need to write the label text only once (in the value attribute), not three times, in the code: <input type="text" value="Search" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue">

Answer (score 139):

If you're using HTML5, you can use the `placeholder` attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
```

Comment: Also, according to [this site](http://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), IE does not support this even until IE9.

Comment: I just drop in something like https://github.com/serby/jquery.placeholder.js/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js for those browsers.

Comment: Placeholder text is not an accessible replacement for the label element: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute

Comment: I would prefer this, rather than the answer marked. +1 for this.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 40):

In my opinion, the best solution involves neither images nor using the input's default value. Rather, it looks something like David Dorward's solution.

It's easy to implement and degrades nicely for screen readers and users with no javascript.

Take a look at the two examples here:
http://attardi.org/labels/

I usually use the second method (labels2) on my forms.

Comment: the solution with the labels behind a transparent input is actually the cleanest implementation of this that i've ever seen.

Comment: Very nice solution - more control over look and feel, no worry about validation/form post interfering.

Comment: Thank you! Looking for a solution to meet an accessibility requirement.  Using the value and placeholder attributes apparently weren't sufficient enough. -_-

Comment: The developer has depreciated this https://github.com/steadicat/labels

Answer (score 5):

The common approach is to use the default value as a label, and then remove it when the field gains the focus.

I really dislike this approach as it has accessibility and usability implications.

Instead, I would start by using a standard  element next to the field.

Then, if JavaScript is active, set a class on an ancestor element which causes some new styles to apply that:

- Relatively position a div that contains the input and label
- Absolutely position the label
- Absolutely position the input on top of the label
- Remove the borders of the input and set its background-color to transparent

Then, and also whenever the input loses the focus, I test to see if the input has a value. If it does, ensure that an ancestor element has a class (e.g. "hide-label"), otherwise ensure that it does not have that class.

Whenever the input gains the focus, set that class.

The stylesheet would use that classname in a selector to hide the label (using text-indent: -9999px; usually).

This approach provides a decent experience for all users, including those with JS disabled and those using screen readers.

Answer (score 5):

I've put together solutions proposed by
@Cory Walker with the extensions from @Rafael
and the one form @Tex witch was a bit complicated for me
and came up with a solution that is hopefully

error-proof with javascript and CSS disabled.

It manipulates with the background-color of the form field to show/hide the label.

```
<head>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
    input {position:relative;background:transparent;} 
-->
</style>

<script>
    function labelPosition() {
        document.getElementById("name").style.position="absolute"; 
            // label is moved behind the textfield using the script, 
            // so it doesnt apply when javascript disabled
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="labelPosition()">

<form>
        <label id="name">Your name</label>
        <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.style.background='transparent';}" onfocus="this.style.background='white'">
</form>

</body>
```

View the script in action: http://mattr.co.uk/work/form_label.html

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="searchbox" onfocus="if (this.value=='search') this.value = ''" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value = 'search'" type="text" value="search">
```

Add an onblur event too.

Answer (score 1):

When you start typing it will disappear.If empty it will appear again.

```
        <%= f.text_field :user_email,:value=>"",:placeholder => "Eg:abc@gmail.com"%>
```

Simplest way...

Answer (score 1):

Please use PlaceHolder.JS its works in all browsers and very easy for non html5 compliant browsers
 http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/

Answer (score 1):

One hint about HTML property *placeholder* and the tag *textarea*, please make sure there is no any space between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`, otherwise the *placeholder* doesn't work, for example:

```
<textarea id="inputJSON" spellcheck="false" placeholder="JSON response string" style="flex: 1;"> </textarea>
```

This won't work, because there is a space between...

Answer (score 0):

use this

style:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .defaultLabel_on { color:#0F0; }
    .defaultLabel_off { color:#CCC; }
</style>
```

html:

javascript:

```
function defaultLabelClean() {
    inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)  {
        if (inputs[i].value == inputs[i].getAttribute("innerLabel")) {
            inputs[i].value = '';
        }
    }
}

function defaultLabelAttachEvents(element, label) {
    element.setAttribute("innerLabel", label);
    element.onfocus = function(e) {
        if (this.value==label) {
            this.className = 'defaultLabel_on';
            this.value = '';
        }
    }
    element.onblur = function(e) {
        if (this.value=='') {
            this.className = 'defaultLabel_off';
            this.value = element.getAttribute("innerLabel");
        }
    }

    if (element.value=='') {
        element.className = 'defaultLabel_off';
        element.value = element.getAttribute("innerLabel");
    }
}


defaultLabelAttachEvents(document.getElementById('MYID'), "MYLABEL");
```

Just remember to call defaultLabelClean() function before submit form.

good work

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a Javascript code for that... 
I think you mean the placeholder attribute. Here is the code:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Your descriptive text goes here...">
```

The default text will be grey-ish and when clicked, it will dissapear!

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to keep the Label and not to use placeholder as mentioned above. Its good for UX as explain here:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/03/ux-contact-forms-essentials-conversions/

Here example with Label inside Input fields:
 codepen.io/jdax/pen/mEBJNa

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but this is what works for me: I see the label itself inside the field more and more often to clean up the page as opposed to outside/above the field or instead of using the placeholder as the field label as it disappears once the field is filled in.

[image]

```
.innerLabel < or other selector > {
  margin-top: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4px;
  color: darkslategray;
}

input[type=text] < or other selector > {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border: solid 1px lightgray;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 11px 2px 0px 4px;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: darkslategray;
  line-height: 31px;
}

    <label for='firstname' class='required innerLabel'>First Name</label><br>
    <input type='text' name="firstname" size='50' required/> <br><br>
    <label for='lastname' class='required innerLabel'>Last Name</label><br>
    <input type='text' name="lastname" size='50' required/> <br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS can be effective!

```
.input-prefix {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.prefix {
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(163, 158, 158);
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 2vmax;
}
```

...

```
<div class="input-prefix">
    <label class="prefix">R$ </label>
    <input type="number" class="text" formControlName="fechado">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Here is a simple example, all it does is overlay an image (with whatever wording you want).  I saw this technique somewhere.  I am using the prototype library so you would need to modify if using something else.  With the image loading after window.load it fails gracefully if javascript is disabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1;" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Fri, Jan 1 1981 08:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <style type="text/css" >

        input.searcher
        {
            background-image: url(/images/search_back.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: scroll;
            background-x-position: left;
            background-y-position: center;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/logist/include/scripts/js/prototype.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="" />

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
    //  <![CDATA[
        function f(e){
            $('q').removeClassName('searcher');
        }

        function b(e){
            if ( $F('q') == '' )
            {
                $('q').addClassName('searcher');
            }
        }

        Event.observe( 'q', 'focus', f);
        Event.observe( 'q', 'blur', b);
        Event.observe( window, 'load', b);

    //  ]]>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```