# Make label inside input element disappear with saved passwords

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have placed labels in my input fields to have explanatory text display in the background and  when the user types in the field, the text disappears.  I'm using the example explained here: [How to create a label inside an <input> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781473/how-to-create-a-label-inside-an-input-element)
and specifically at http://attardi.org/

When the password though is saved by the browser such as in Google chrome, the text becomes garbled as in this image (this is currently on my local computer):
[image: display and saved password text]

The background text is not disappearing for saved passwords.  Any help would be appreciative - thanks.

Comment: its called a watermark - Google it - it should not be done with labels

Comment: @ScottSelby why not? And, looking at the example, it's not a label but a span inside a label. Looks perfectly legit to me.

Comment: I guess it works , I just think that when you type watermark with text in the textbox its easier to control browser autocomplete ,

Comment: there are [plugins](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) for this.

Comment: One of my friends pointed this out that its an issue with Google Chrome as a bug even with the placeholder attribute also: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117661

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also take advantage of the new `placeholder` attribute. [Read about it here](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp).

No `IE` support, though.

Option 2 would be using `Jquery`. Since you're already using `Jquery` for the `label` solution, you could add code that checks the `value` of the `input` after the document has loaded then show or hide the `label` accordingly.

This code would go inside the [document ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `placeholder` attribute – it's so simple:

```
<input type="email" placeholder="email" />
```

Literally, that's it; the browser will take care of the behavior.

Yes, it won't work in IE (until IE10 is released) – but you've already got labels next to the fields anyway, so it's not like IE users won't be able to tell which fields are which.

Comment: I use the same setup on another page and I did not have labels/explanatory fields next to these text boxes.  So I need to implement this attribute without placeholders because of it not being supported in IE.  I would really like to keep these fields without the fields next to them.

Comment: Ah, I was just basing my answer off of your screenshot. You might want to try the [Replaceholder](http://designindevelopment.com/plugins/replaceholder-jquery-plugin/) plugin to add IE support (it will "convert" the placeholder text to a value that behaves the same way).

Answer (score 0):

I investigated further, and this only occurred in Google Chrome and not Mozilla Firefox.  My setup was correct and looks like it might in fact be a bug in Chrome.  See issue log: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117661

This also looks like it will occur for the placeholder attribute too when Chrome tries to do password autosave process and doesn't look to see if there is a previous inputted value.

Thanks for the input from all.